# How to show a different "store view" when browsing from Mobile and Desktop

Tags: magento-1.8, theme, store-view, mobile

I have read loads of tutorials on how to set up a specific "store view" for the mobile version of my magento store.

My problem is that nobody really explain on how (after the different store views are being created) you can have magento show automatically one store view when browsing from mobile and another one when browsing on the desktop.

Where is the place where to insert the user agent expression?

Please note: *I am not looking for how to change the theme*, but instead how to show a different store view. What I need to do is being able to "switch on and off" different pages or static blocks when browsing the same theme from mobile or desktop.

maybe you can help me with this.

Answer (score 1):

[Magebase explains it quite well.](http://magebase.com/magento-tutorials/magento-design-exceptions-explained/)

It is not changing the storeview, but changing the theme. You can add an exception, like:

```
iPhone|iPod|BlackBerry|Palm|Googlebot-Mobile|Mobile|mobile|mobi|Windows Mobile|Safari Mobile|Android|Opera Mini
```

and then define a theme which is used instead, like `iphone` (included) or `mobile` (to implement by you)

To change the storeview, you have to change the `MAGE_RUN_CODE` in `$_SERVER`, this can be done on two ways:

1. [in VHost config / .htaccess via](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_setenvif.html#setenvif)

   ```
   SetEnvIf Host www\.domain2\.com MAGE_RUN_CODE={storecode}
   ```

   so you can check the user agent (read the doc) and change the storeview based on this. Putting this in the VHost config is the best way (and removing the .htaccess)
2. via index.php

## index.php:82

```
$mageRunCode = isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE']) ? _SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE'] : '';
$mageRunType = isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE']) ? _SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE'] : 'store';
```

Then another store view is loaded.

Comment: I have read that article, but that covers only on how to switch themes. What about store views? Is that impossible? I will want to use the same theme (i have a responsive theme), is the content (statick blocks) that I would like to be different. Thanks

Comment: updated answer.

Comment: This isn't recommended because you can't do things like alter the catalog, static blocks, etc.

Comment: I read this and I don't get it. I'm also trying to load a different store view for mobile users (www.m.myDomain.com) but where do I define these exceptions you are talking about and what excatly do I put into the .htaccess file??

Comment: did you click the magebase link? @Allysin